# Adding an image to only one node within a Tree View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, telerik, treeview, telerik-mvc

I'm currently working on modifying a Tree View control (Telerik MVC Extensions) for a customer request.  Their request is a simple one: if an item within the tree has an Attachment, add a paperclip beside the node to identify it.

I have so far been able to do so but, found a small hiccup with this.  I can add the image to certain nodes that have an Attachment, however, all nodes that don't should have no image (by that, I mean they should appear normal within the tree).  Instead though, I find that the tree places a blank the size of the paperclip image.

Is there a way to dynamically turn off this blank (aka not add an Image Url if unnecessary)?  Below is my code where I'm executing this process (is done on the expansion method of the tree due that only the bottom level shows the Attachments).

Navigation Controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetNextTreeViewLevel(TreeViewItem node)
{
    ...
    //If bottom layer, then execute the following
    var data = _TreeRepo.GetProcessesByParcel(int.Parse(values[1]), cntTreeList);
    nodes = from item in data
              select new TreeViewItem
              {
                 Text = item.strProcess,
                 Value = "PR" + "," + item.cntProcess.ToString(),
                 LoadOnDemand = false,
                 Enabled = true,
                 Selected = SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Length > 0
                                        && SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Split('~').Length > 3
                                        && decimal.Parse(SelectedSearchResult.ToString()
                                            .Split('~')
                                            .Last()
                                            .Substring(2)) == item.cntProcess
                 ImageUrl = item.ysnHasAttachment.HasValue && item.ysnHasAttachment.Value == 1
                              ? @"/Content/NewImages/attachment.png"
                              : string.Empty
              };
    return new JsonResult { Data = nodes };
}
```

Screen shots of what it looks like without/with code for Image Url:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I at long last came up with a solution to this issue.  The problem was how I was getting my data added to the nodes.  The original logic was doing a Linq query after fetching the data to get an IEnumerable object.

Because of that, every node was trying to add an image (even if there was none).  Hence the weird looking space.  Below is how I reworked this logic to correctly get my data.

```
var processNodes = new List<TreeViewItem>();
var data = _TreeRepo.GetProcessesByParcel(int.Parse(values[1]), cntTreeList);

foreach (var item in data)
{
    #region Process has at least one Attachment
    if (item.ysnHasAttachment.HasValue && item.ysnHasAttachment.Value == 1)
        processNodes.Add(new TreeViewItem
        {
           Text = item.strProcess,
           Value = "PR" + "," + item.cntProcess.ToString(),
           LoadOnDemand = false,
           Enabled = true,
           Selected = SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Length > 0
                        && SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Split('~').Length > 3
                        && decimal.Parse(SelectedSearchResult.ToString()
                        .Split('~')
                        .Last()
                        .Substring(2)) == item.cntProcess,
           ImageUrl = "/Content/NewImages/smallAttachment.png"
        });
    #endregion
    #region Process has no Attachments
    else
        processNodes.Add(new TreeViewItem
        {
           Text = item.strProcess,
           Value = "PR" + "," + item.cntProcess.ToString(),
           LoadOnDemand = false,
           Enabled = true,
           Selected = SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Length > 0
                        && SelectedSearchResult.ToString().Split('~').Length > 3
                        && decimal.Parse(SelectedSearchResult.ToString()
                        .Split('~')
                        .Last()
                        .Substring(2)) == item.cntProcess
        }
   #endregion
}
nodes = processNodes;
```

At this point, you can now return the nodes.  Those that should have had an Attachment icon will, and those that shouldn't won't.  Funny how 4 months later, you can come up with something off the cuff.